# Is input impedance of an opamp independent from its input's frequency components?

Tags: operational-amplifier, frequency

If input impedance of an op-amp is infinite (theoretically), does frequency of an input signal have any effect on input impedance of the op-amp?

Comment: Are you asking about the properties of a practical or an ideal opamp? because an ideal opamp has absolutely no frequency dependence (of course) - it's ideal!

Comment: im asking practical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, or more precisely, *ideally*, the answer is no.  If

$$Z_{in}(\omega) \rightarrow \infty$$

for an ideal op-amp, then there is *zero* input current for *any* input voltage of *any* frequency.

But, this isn't surprising or, for that matter, very interesting.  Ideal op-amps are an *abstraction* that, in the appropriate context, are a good approximation to physically realizable op-amps.

In other words, for *real* op-amps, the input impedance is finite (though relatively large) and varies with frequency.

Answer (score 3):

If something has an infinite impedance then  any frequency cannot affect it however, it's never going to be infinite and as frequency rises the small amount of capacitance associated with the input will start to become significant even if the input resistance stays in the Giga ohm range.

The frequency won't affect the capacitance but the amplitude of the voltage may cause this capacitance to change slightly on some devices. See varactor diodes and miller capacitance changes with applied voltages.

Answer (score 1):

You just said the input impedance is infinite.  If it is always infinite, then obviously it it doesn't vary with frequency.  This question makes no sense.

Comment: is that really infinitive or only in theory?

Comment: @user16307, there are no actual infinities in nature.  The ideal op-amp is an abstraction.  Physical op-amps have finite input impedance but, in the appropriate context, the input impedance is *effectively* infinite, i.e., the ideal approximation is valid to the precision one is working to.